# Represent condition as a formula

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

This situation is part of code I'm working on :

```
// All are Bitvector of length 4
node[i], V1, V2, V3;
```

I'm trying to make sure that node[i]  should not contain any of other three vectors i.e V1 , V2 and V3 .
For example Lets say `V1` is `1001`, `V2` is `0111`, `V3` is `0011`.

One trivial way I can think is stating it as `(node[i] & V1) != V1` and similar for others.

I'm thinking of representing as a formula / clause , that'll help making my code optimized. Because I'm iteration over whole possible V's and then checking one by one with the node.

> Is there a better way to do the same?

Comment: You're trying to check wheter `node[i]` doesn't have any bit set that is set in any of the V-Vectors. Did I get that right?

Comment: I can't imagine doing it any other way than the one discussed in the question. The idea from the question seems pretty much the best option.

Comment: No i'm trying to get notion that not all bits that are set in any V's should be set in node. For example in this 0101 is valid configuration of node. and so is 0100. Doing Or's to all V's and then & is trivial solution comes in mind if i want to do it. But i want not all bits of any V's effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of

   ```
   (((node[i] & V1) != V1) && 
    ((node[i] & V2) != V2) && 
    ((node[i] & V3) != V3))
   ```

with the following set, any `node[i]` that matches `V2` matches `V3` and so only 2 tests are needed.

```
 V1 is 1001, V2 is 0111, V3 is 0011

    (((node[i] & V1) != V1) && 
     ((node[i] & V2) != V2))
```

Of course, which tests are needed varies with `V1, V2, V3`.

Details: See [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)

2. With only 4-bit vector, pre-compute a `valid[]` table.  In `precompute()`, go through all 16 combinations per the original `(((node[i] & V1) != V1) && ...` test.

   ```
   bool valid[1u<<4];
   precompute(valid, V1, V2, V3);

   loop
      if (valid[node[i]]) ...
   ```

Comment: Chux point taken for 1.  yeah as its dynamic in my code how many such V's are there so 1 and wht's there configuration will be so won't help me much. Analysis the second part of suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @user2754673 Presenting the expect range of Vector counts, BIt Width and Node Count does drive the candidate solutions.  I assume Node Count is large, Vector count modest and Bit Width <= 16.

Comment: Actual bitwidth i'm using is 10.

Comment: So a look-up table of 1024 is not so bad.  How many nodes, vectors?

Comment: Total 10 nodes. 10 vectors

Comment: I'm still thinking but it should be easier than this. I have to allow . !V1 !V2 ! V3 as valid possibility. So trying to build a combination and failing. may be this is the best we can do..